# Errors when using openNLP chunker

Tags: gate

I am trying to use the openNLP chunker like this:

```
Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories( new File(Gate.getGateHome().getAbsolutePath()
                                         + "/plugins/OpenNLP").toURI().toURL());
ProcessingResource chunkPr = (ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.opennlp.OpenNlpChunker", Factory.newFeatureMap());
annieController.add(chunkPr);
```

However I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: opennlp.maxent.io.BinaryGISModelReader.getModel()Lopennlp/maxent/GISModel;
at gate.opennlp.OpenNlpChunker.getModel(OpenNlpChunker.java:59)
at gate.opennlp.OpenNlpChunker.init(OpenNlpChunker.java:190)
```

I can't figure out how to get rid of this exception.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve it.

**1st:**

Switch to later GATE version. In latest gate build it works just fine. I tested it with  gate-7.2-SNAPSHOT-build4745-ALL. You can take one from [Jenkins continuous integration server](http://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/GATE-Nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/). I did not test [latest stable release](https://gate.ac.uk/download/#latest) but I'm sure it should help you as well.

**2nd:**

If you are constrained by your existing version of GATE (i guess it something like 5.1...6) it 
makes things more complex.

If you have OpenNLPPlugun's source code in your GATE installation, just rebuild plugin using Ant. You will find Ant's build.xml in $GATE_HOME$/plugins/OpenNLP folder.

**3rd (Worst case. If 1st & 2nd way didn't help):**

In general, you have to resole dependency conflict between two (or more!) different version of OpenNLP libraries.

The problem is that your OpenNLPChunker is quite old version of GATE's processing resource from Ontotext. It depends from particular version of opennlp.maxent.io.BinaryGISModelReader class. It hard to say exactly what happen on your computer without detailed information about your GATE configuration. But things generally happen in following way:

You have several versions of OpenNLP libraries in your classpath at runtime. Some additional plugin or some another module are dependent from OpenNLP library. (It doesn't have to be a GATE's plugun but it's presented in Java classpath) That plugin (or any code) loads another version of opennlp.maxent.io.BinaryGISModelReader class as a dependency. After that, you are trying to load OpenNLPChunker which gets wrong version (already loaded by ClassLoader) of opennlp.maxent.io.BinaryGISModelReader class. During attempt to call "getModel()" method you are getting NoSuchMethodError exception. You have to make sure there is only one OpenNLP library.

PS:

OpenNLPChunker was rewritten by Ian Roberts in later versions of GATE and doesn't depend from versions of opennlp.maxent.io.BinaryGISModelReader class. So 1st option would be easiest solution.